# how to change values in a df specifying by index contain in multiple lists, and each list for one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have a list where I have all the index of values to be replaced. I have to change them in 8 diferent columns with 8 diferent lists. The replacement could be a simple string.
How can I do it?
I have more than 20 diferent columns in this df

Eg:

```
list1 = [0,1,2]
list2 =[2,4]
list8 = ...
```

sustitution = 'no data'

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| marcos | peter |
| Julila | mike |
| Fran | Ramon |
| Pedri | Gavi |
| Olmo | Torres |

```
OUTPUT: 

| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| no data  | peter    |
| no data  | mike     |
| no data  | no data  |
| Pedri    | Gavi     |
| Olmo     | no data  |`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with zipped lists and columns names:

```
list1 = [0,1,2]
list2 =[2,4]

L = [list1,list2]
cols = ['Column A','Column B']

sustitution = 'no data'

for c, i in zip(cols, L):
    df.loc[i, c] = sustitution
print (df)
  Column A Column B
0  no data    peter
1  no data     mike
2  no data  no data
3    Pedri     Gavi
4     Olmo  no data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but appears: 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @DEA - It was copy error, need `for c, i in zip(df.columns, L):` instead `for c, i in L`

Comment: Thanks, now is executing without error, but do not change values properly.
Notice that df have more than 8 columns but I only want to change this specific 8

Comment: @DEA - I change solution by this requirement, you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74557243/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
list1 = [0,1,2]
list2 = [2,4]

lists = [list1, list2]

col = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lists)), list(map(len, lists)))
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
row = np.concatenate(lists)
# array([0, 1, 2, 2, 4])

df.values[row, col] = 'no data'
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B
0  no data    peter
1  no data     mike
2  no data  no data
3    Pedri     Gavi
4     Olmo  no data
```